# Mapbox GL Filter symbols and Add custom icons with Markers

Tags: mapbox

I have a problem with Mapbox GL: starting from the example Filter symbols by toggling to list (https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-markers/) I have to Add custom icons with Markers (https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-marker-icons/). In practice I would like to customize the icons while maintaining the filter.

```
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = '<your access token here>';
var geojson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "icon": "theatre",
"iconSize": [50, 50]
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-77.038659, 38.931567]
        }
    },  {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "icon": "music",
"iconSize": [40, 40]
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-77.007481, 38.876516]
        }
    }]
};

var filterGroup = document.getElementById('filter-group');
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
    center: [-77.04, 38.907],
    zoom: 11.15
});

map.on('load', function() {
    // Add a GeoJSON source containing place coordinates and information.
    map.addSource("places", {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data":geojson
    });

    geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {
var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'marker';
    el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://placekitten.com/g/' + marker.properties.iconSize.join('/') + '/)';
    el.style.width = marker.properties.iconSize[0] + 'px';
    el.style.height = marker.properties.iconSize[1] + 'px';
        var symbol = feature.properties['icon'];
        var layerID = 'poi-' + symbol;

        // Add a layer for this symbol type if it hasn't been added already.
        if (!map.getLayer(layerID)) {
            map.addLayer({
                "id": layerID,
                "type": "symbol",
                "source": "geojson",
                "layout": {
                    "icon-image": symbol + "-15",
                    "icon-allow-overlap": true
                },
                "filter": ["==", "icon", symbol]
            });

            // Add checkbox and label elements for the layer.
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.type = 'checkbox';
            input.id = layerID;
            input.checked = true;
            filterGroup.appendChild(input);

            var label = document.createElement('label');
            label.setAttribute('for', layerID);
            label.textContent = symbol;
            filterGroup.appendChild(label);

            // When the checkbox changes, update the visibility of the layer.
            input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
                map.setLayoutProperty(layerID, 'visibility',
                    e.target.checked ? 'visible' : 'none');
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```